# Jquery mobile with a vertical slider

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Im trying to make a "glass of water" getting filled as the slider is moved up and down.

I made a fiddle with the progress so far, but the slider is horizontal.

http://jsfiddle.net/FsvmC/3/

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="glass">
        <div class="water"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="slider-1">Slider:</label>
        <input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="0" max="100" value="10">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
$("#slider-1").on("slidestop", function (e) {
    $('.water').animate({
        height: $(this).val() + '%'
    }, 1000)
});
});

.glass {
position: relative;
margin: 10px auto;
height: 200px;
width: 80px;
border-style: none solid solid solid;
border-width: 10px;
border-color: white;
}
.water {
width: 100%;
height: 10%;
position: absolute;
background-color: blue;
bottom: 0;
}
```

I've tried a few things at this point.
Plugins, none of them just felt right. All had flaws, css needed hacks to stay inline or it just plain ruined other functions in JQM like the switch button.

Considered using the HTML5 range input with webkit slider-vertical, again conflicting with the JQM slider.

Wondering if anyone has a suggestion to a possible solution, that either doesnt interferer with the current JQM at all, or does it in a way so the code ends up being easy to maintain, compared to the plugins.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://www.elmundio.net/projects/verticalSlider/)?

Comment: @itchy Yeah, I did. But it needs a major overhaul, even his example is flawed. And id rater not mess up the current implementation of JQM.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I need something similar.

Comment: @tman Nope, never did. Had to change the design. Even the things that kinda worked, had flawed touch functionality.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out? What was your changed design? I have been spending days looking at every available JS GUI toolkit/framework and am astounded that all of them seem terrible. Is the answer to roll your own widgets? And why do so many frameworks seem to have no significant activity for last year or two? Where has all that effort gone? Sorry for the mini-rant...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [vertical slider on GitHub developed for jQuery Mobile](https://github.com/damienromito/jquery-vertical-slider) from December '13 (jQuery Mobile 1.0).

The author, Damien Romito, has this to say:

> Jquery Mobile don't allow to display slider vertically. I need it to working on a project, then I continued the work of @elmundio87

I have tried it with the current version of jQuery Mobile (1.4.5) and can confirm it doesn't work. However since the question was asked Nov '13 it seems a good answer. Perhaps it can be updated to work with the latest version. My search is continuing and I will update here if I find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works. I was looking for something like that

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/euqMu/light/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var iValue = 50;
    $("#lblVertical").text(iValue);
    $("#lblHorizontal").text(iValue);
    $("#sliderVer").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        orientation: "vertical",
        value: iValue,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#lblVertical").text(ui.value);
        }
    });

     $("#sliderHoz").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        value: iValue,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#lblHorizontal").text(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery Mobile has no orientation option on its .slider(). This is for jQuery UI and the question is for jQuery Mobile. See docs here: api.jquerymobile.com/slider

Answer (score 0):

There is [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iancboswell/eM7Rh/) sourced [from this thread on the jQuery forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-there-a-vertical-slider-for-jquery-mobile#14737000005452125) by Ian Boswell July '14.

```js
// vertical slider extension
// add data-vertical="true" to the input to enable verticality
// data-height lets you set height in px
$.widget("mobile.slider", $.mobile.slider, {
    options: {
        vertical: false,
        height: 250
    },

    _create: function() {
        if (this.options.vertical) {
            // TODO: Each of these should have comments explain what they're for
            var self = this,
                control = this.element,
                trackTheme = this.options.trackTheme || $.mobile.getAttribute( control[ 0 ], "theme" ),
                trackThemeClass = trackTheme ? " ui-bar-" + trackTheme : " ui-bar-inherit",
                cornerClass = ( this.options.corners || control.jqmData( "corners" ) ) ? " ui-corner-all" : "",
                miniClass = ( this.options.mini || control.jqmData( "mini" ) ) ? " ui-mini" : "",
                cType = control[ 0 ].nodeName.toLowerCase(),
                isToggleSwitch = ( cType === "select" ),
                isRangeslider = control.parent().is( ":jqmData(role='rangeslider')" ),
                selectClass = ( isToggleSwitch ) ? "ui-slider-switch" : "",
                controlID = control.attr( "id" ),
                $label = $( "[for='" + controlID + "']" ),
                labelID = $label.attr( "id" ) || controlID + "-label",
                trueMin = !isToggleSwitch ? parseFloat( control.attr( "min" ) ) : 0,
                trueMax =  !isToggleSwitch ? parseFloat( control.attr( "max" ) ) : control.find( "option" ).length-1,
                min = trueMax * -1,
                max = trueMin * -1,
                step = window.parseFloat( control.attr( "step" ) || 1 ),
                domHandle = document.createElement( "a" ),
                handle = $( domHandle ),
                domSlider = document.createElement( "div" ),
                slider = $( domSlider ),
                valuebg = this.options.highlight && !isToggleSwitch ? (function() {
                    var bg = document.createElement( "div" );
                    bg.className = "ui-slider-bg " + $.mobile.activeBtnClass;
                    return $( bg ).prependTo( slider );
                })() : false,
                options,
                wrapper,
                j, length,
                i, optionsCount, origTabIndex,
                side, activeClass, sliderImg;

            $label.attr( "id", labelID );
            this.isToggleSwitch = isToggleSwitch;

            domHandle.setAttribute( "href", "#" );
            domSlider.setAttribute( "role", "application" );
            domSlider.className = [ this.isToggleSwitch ? "ui-slider ui-slider-track ui-shadow-inset " : "ui-slider-track ui-shadow-inset ", selectClass, trackThemeClass, cornerClass, miniClass ].join( "" );
            domHandle.className = "ui-slider-handle";
            domSlider.appendChild( domHandle );

            handle.attr({
                "role": "slider",
                "aria-valuemin": min,
                "aria-valuemax": max,
                "aria-valuenow": this._value(),
                "aria-valuetext": this._value(),
                "title": this._value(),
                "aria-labelledby": labelID
            });

            $.extend( this, {
                slider: slider,
                handle: handle,
                control: control,
                type: cType,
                step: step,
                max: max,
                min: min,
                valuebg: valuebg,
                isRangeslider: isRangeslider,
                dragging: false,
                beforeStart: null,
                userModified: false,
                mouseMoved: false
            });

            if ( isToggleSwitch ) {
                // TODO: restore original tabindex (if any) in a destroy method
                origTabIndex = control.attr( "tabindex" );
                if ( origTabIndex ) {
                    handle.attr( "tabindex", origTabIndex );
                }
                control.attr( "tabindex", "-1" ).focus(function() {
                    $( this ).blur();
                    handle.focus();
                });

                wrapper = document.createElement( "div" );
                wrapper.className = "ui-slider-inneroffset";

                for ( j = 0, length = domSlider.childNodes.length; j < length; j++ ) {
                    wrapper.appendChild( domSlider.childNodes[j] );
                }

                domSlider.appendChild( wrapper );

                // slider.wrapInner( "<div class='ui-slider-inneroffset'></div>" );

                // make the handle move with a smooth transition
                handle.addClass( "ui-slider-handle-snapping" );

                options = control.find( "option" );

                for ( i = 0, optionsCount = options.length; i < optionsCount; i++ ) {
                    side = !i ? "b" : "a";
                    activeClass = !i ? "" : " " + $.mobile.activeBtnClass;
                    sliderImg = document.createElement( "span" );

                    sliderImg.className = [ "ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-", side, activeClass ].join( "" );
                    sliderImg.setAttribute( "role", "img" );
                    sliderImg.appendChild( document.createTextNode( options[i].innerHTML ) );
                    $( sliderImg ).prependTo( slider );
                }

                self._labels = $( ".ui-slider-label", slider );

            }

            // monitor the input for updated values
            control.addClass( isToggleSwitch ? "ui-slider-switch" : "ui-slider-input" );

            this._on( control, {
                "change": "_controlChange",
                "keyup": "_controlKeyup",
                "blur": "_controlBlur",
                "vmouseup": "_controlVMouseUp"
            });

            slider.bind( "vmousedown", $.proxy( this._sliderVMouseDown, this ) )
                .bind( "vclick", false );

            // We have to instantiate a new function object for the unbind to work properly
            // since the method itself is defined in the prototype (causing it to unbind everything)
            this._on( document, { "vmousemove": "_preventDocumentDrag" });
            this._on( slider.add( document ), { "vmouseup": "_sliderVMouseUp" });

            slider.insertAfter( control );

            // wrap in a div for styling purposes
            if ( !isToggleSwitch && !isRangeslider ) {
                wrapper = this.options.mini ? "<div class='ui-slider ui-mini'>" : "<div class='ui-slider'>";

                control.add( slider ).wrapAll( wrapper );
            }

            // bind the handle event callbacks and set the context to the widget instance
            this._on( this.handle, {
                "vmousedown": "_handleVMouseDown",
                "keydown": "_handleKeydown",
                "keyup": "_handleKeyup"
            });

            this.handle.bind( "vclick", false );

            this._handleFormReset();

            this.refresh( undefined, undefined, true );

            this.slider.attr("style", "width:20px !important; margin: 0 0 20px 14px !important; height:"+this.options.height+"px !important;")
            $(this.control).detach()
            $(this.slider).parent().append(this.control)
            $(this.slider).parent().css("margin-bottom", (this.options.height + 30) + "px")
        } else {
            this._super()
        }
    },
    
    _value: function() {
        if (!this.options.vertical) {
            this._super()
        } else {
            return  this.isToggleSwitch ? this.element[0].selectedIndex : parseFloat( this.element.val() * -1 );
        }
    },

    refresh: function(val, isfromControl, preventInputUpdate) {
        if (!this.options.vertical) {
            this._super(val, isfromControl, preventInputUpdate)
        } else {
            var self = this,
                parentTheme = $.mobile.getAttribute( this.element[ 0 ], "theme" ),
                theme = this.options.theme || parentTheme,
                themeClass =  theme ? " ui-btn-" + theme : "",
                trackTheme = this.options.trackTheme || parentTheme,
                trackThemeClass = trackTheme ? " ui-bar-" + trackTheme : " ui-bar-inherit",
                cornerClass = this.options.corners ? " ui-corner-all" : "",
                miniClass = this.options.mini ? " ui-mini" : "",
                top, height, data, tol,
                pyStep, percent,
                control, isInput, optionElements, min, max, step,
                newval, valModStep, alignValue, percentPerStep,
                handlePercent, aPercent, bPercent,
                valueChanged;

            self.slider[0].className = [ this.isToggleSwitch ? "ui-slider ui-slider-switch ui-slider-track ui-shadow-inset" : "ui-slider-track ui-shadow-inset", trackThemeClass, cornerClass, miniClass ].join( "" );
            if ( this.options.disabled || this.element.prop( "disabled" ) ) {
                this.disable();
            }

            // set the stored value for comparison later
            this.value = this._value();
            if ( this.options.highlight && !this.isToggleSwitch && this.slider.find( ".ui-slider-bg" ).length === 0 ) {
                this.valuebg = (function() {
                    var bg = document.createElement( "div" );
                    bg.className = "ui-slider-bg " + $.mobile.activeBtnClass;
                    return $( bg ).prependTo( self.slider );
                })();
            }
            this.handle.addClass( "ui-btn" + themeClass + " ui-shadow" );

            control = this.element;
            isInput = !this.isToggleSwitch;
            optionElements = isInput ? [] : control.find( "option" );

// invert min and max
            trueMin =  isInput ? parseFloat( control.attr( "min" ) ) : 0
            trueMax = isInput ? parseFloat( control.attr( "max" ) ) : optionElements.length - 1;
            min = trueMax * -1
            max = trueMin * -1

            /* original
            min =  isInput ? parseFloat( control.attr( "min" ) ) : 0
            max = isInput ? parseFloat( control.attr( "max" ) ) : optionElements.length - 1;*/


            step = ( isInput && parseFloat( control.attr( "step" ) ) > 0 ) ? parseFloat( control.attr( "step" ) ) : 1;

            if ( typeof val === "object" ) {
                data = val;
                // a slight tolerance helped get to the ends of the slider
                tol = 8;

                top = this.slider.offset().top;
                height = this.slider.height();
                pyStep = height/((max-min)/step);
                if ( !this.dragging ||
                        data.pageY < top - tol ||
                        data.pageY > top + height + tol ) {
                    return;
                }
                if ( pyStep > 1 ) {
                    percent = ( ( data.pageY - top ) / height ) * 100;
                } else {
                    percent = Math.round( ( ( data.pageY - top ) / height ) * 100 );
                }
            } else {
                if ( val == null ) {
                    val = isInput ? parseFloat( control.val() * -1 || 0 ) : control[0].selectedIndex;
                }
                percent = ( parseFloat( val ) - min ) / ( max - min ) * 100;
            }

            if ( isNaN( percent ) ) {
                return;
            }

            newval = ( percent / 100 ) * ( max - min ) + min;

            //from jQuery UI slider, the following source will round to the nearest step
            valModStep = ( newval - min ) % step;
            alignValue = newval - valModStep;

            if ( Math.abs( valModStep ) * 2 >= step ) {
                alignValue += ( valModStep > 0 ) ? step : ( -step );
            }

            percentPerStep = 100/((max-min)/step);
            // Since JavaScript has problems with large floats, round
            // the final value to 5 digits after the decimal point (see jQueryUI: #4124)
            newval = parseFloat( alignValue.toFixed(5) );

            if ( typeof pyStep === "undefined" ) {
                pyStep = height / ( (max-min) / step );
            }
            if ( pyStep > 1 && isInput ) {
                percent = ( newval - min ) * percentPerStep * ( 1 / step );
            }
            if ( percent < 0 ) {
                percent = 0;
            }

            if ( percent > 100 ) {
                percent = 100;
            }

            if ( newval < min ) {
                newval = min;
            }

            if ( newval > max ) {
                newval = max;
            }
            
            newval *= -1;

            this.handle.css( "top", percent + "%" );
            this.handle.css("margin-left", "-5px");

            this.handle[0].setAttribute( "aria-valuenow", isInput ? newval : optionElements.eq( newval ).attr( "value" ) );

            this.handle[0].setAttribute( "aria-valuetext", isInput ? newval : optionElements.eq( newval ).getEncodedText() );

            this.handle[0].setAttribute( "title", isInput ? newval : optionElements.eq( newval ).getEncodedText() );

            if ( this.valuebg ) {
                this.valuebg.css( "height", percent + "%" );
            }

            // drag the label heights
            if ( this._labels ) {
                handlePercent = this.handle.height() / this.slider.height() * 100;
                aPercent = percent && handlePercent + ( 100 - handlePercent ) * percent / 100;
                bPercent = percent === 100 ? 0 : Math.min( handlePercent + 100 - aPercent, 100 );

                this._labels.each(function() {
                    var ab = $( this ).hasClass( "ui-slider-label-a" );
                    $( this ).height( ( ab ? aPercent : bPercent  ) + "%" );
                });
            }

            if ( !preventInputUpdate ) {
                valueChanged = false;

                // update control"s value
                if ( isInput ) {
                    valueChanged = control.val() !== newval;
                    control.val( newval );
                } else {
                    valueChanged = control[ 0 ].selectedIndex !== newval;
                    control[ 0 ].selectedIndex = newval;
                }
                if ( this._trigger( "beforechange", val ) === false) {
                        return false;
                }
                if ( !isfromControl && valueChanged ) {
                    control.trigger( "change" );
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="vert">Vertical Slider:</label>
            <input type="range" name="vert" id="vert" data-vertical="true" value="0" min="-20" max="20"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="range" name="vert2" id="vert2" data-vertical="true" value="0" min="0" max="20"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="range" name="vert3" id="vert3" data-vertical="true" value="0" min="-20" max="0"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<label for="horiz">Horizontal Slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="horiz" id="horiz" value="0" min="-20" max="20">
```